# No workspaces nor switcher in ubuntu-gnome-desktop

Tags: gnome, workspaces

Running Xubuntu 16.04, ran `sudo apt install ubuntu-gnome-desktop`, then logged out and back in with gnome desktop environment and now my keyboard shortcuts for switching desktops do not work even though they are correctly configured in the keyboard shortcuts.

Does ubuntu gnome even support workspaces without installing another tool?

Comment: Do you see something like this: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/lcGEkdp0pfE/maxresdefault.jpg when you hover over/ click on **Activities**? Workplaces are on the right side.

Comment: Unfortunately not and I could not locate something akin to the Xubuntu workspace settings.

Comment: Nevermind, I just reinstalled the packages and now it works. Probably a user error somewhere